# Best practice for queueing events in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I have a WPF (MVVM) project where I have multiple view-models, each with a button that launches different analyses on the same data source, which in this case is a file. The file cannot be shared, so if the buttons are pressed near the same time the second call will fail.

I need a way to queue the button clicks so that each analysis can be run sequentially, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I tried using a static `Semaphore`, `SemaphoreSlim` and `Mutex`, but they appear to stop everything (the `Wait()` function appears to block the currently running analysis). I tried a `lock()` command with a static object but it didn't seem to block either event (I get the file share error). I also tried a thread pool (with a max concurrent thread count of 1), but it gives threading errors updating the UI (this may be solvable with `Invoke()` calls).

My question is what might be considered best practice in this situation with WPF?

EDIT: I created a mockup which exhibits the problem I'm having.  It is at http://1drv.ms/1s4oQ1T.

Comment: The button presses should already be queued through the WPF Dispatcher class. Are you somehow launching the analysis on a worker thread?

Comment: I am not using a worker thread.  I just uploaded a sample.  Inside the real app we have a progress bar that uses a Dispatcher call to keep the UI responsive.

Comment: Do you want to queue clicks, or queue tasks that do something on a click?

Comment: I suppose it is more about queuing tasks; the real analyses can take several seconds to minutes, and they access the same data source that cannot be shared, so they need to be queued to run sequentially.  If it is easier to do with clicks, I would be interested too.

Comment: Are you sure you want to queue another task or disable the button while the first task is running?

Comment: It is likely that users will want to set multiple analyses running and walk away, so queuing is preferred.

Comment: Sounds like a confusing UI.  You say that "if they are pressed near the same time the second call will fail" so it doesn't sound like each would take much time; queuing sounds like it makes for a complicated UI.  e.g. progress of multiple items, updating the UI when multiple items complete, etc...

Comment: They use a common resource, so the second fails when the first is still working on the data.

Answer (score 1):

I would do two things to solve this problem:

First, encapsulate the analysis operations in a *command* pattern. If you aren't familiar with it, the simplest implementation is an interface with a single function `Execute`. When you want to perform an analysis operation, just create one of these. You could also use the built-in `ICommand` interface to help, but be aware that this interface has more to it than the generic command pattern.

Of course, creation is only half the battle, so after doing so I would add it to a `BlockingCollection`. This collection is .NET's solution to the Producer-Consumer problem. Have a background thread that consumes this collection (executing the command objects contained within) using a `foreach` on the collection's `GetConsumingEnumerable` method and your buttons will "feed" it.

```
foreach (var item in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    item.Execute();
}
```

MSDN for Blocking Collection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx

Now, all the semaphores, waits, etc. are done for you, and you can just add an operation to the queue (if it needs to be a queue, consider using `ConcurrentQueue` as the backing collection for `BlockingCollection`) and return on the UI thread. The background thread will pick the task up and run it.

You *will* need to `Invoke` any UI updates from the background thread of course, no getting around that issue :).

Comment: I uploaded a sample project.  In it and the real app the events are hooked up to commands via MVVM.  Do you have any samples of the BlockingCollection?

Comment: @WalterWilliams In my design, the MVVM commands would simply add a different command object to the queue for processing.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Basically what I'm suggesting (other than using `BlockingCollection` so its thread safe and easy to consume). `ICommand` has additional "baggage" that a standard command pattern wouldn't, but it would work just fine here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I thinking ICommand just because this is a WPF app; but, if they're executed outside of WPF, it could be more than necessary.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Totally agree. It doesn't *really* matter, and only the OP knows which to use. I've edited to include it though.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is an *asynchronous* queue, so that you can enqueue these tasks without actually having anything blocking your threads.  `SemaphoreSlim` actually has a `WaitAsync` method that makes creating such a queue rather simple:

```
public class TaskQueue
{
    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    public TaskQueue()
    {
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    }

    public async Task<T> Enqueue<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskGenerator)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
    public async Task Enqueue(Func<Task> taskGenerator)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to enqueue operations that will be all executed sequentially, rather than in parallel, and without blocking any threads at any time.  The operations can also be any type of asynchronous operation, whether that is CPU bound work in another thread, IO bound work, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a queue, in a scheduling object shared by the view-models, with a consumer task that waits on the queue to have an item added to it. When a button is pressed, the view-model adds a work item to the queue. The consumer task takes one item from the queue each time, does the analysis contained in the work item, and then checks the queue for another item, waiting for more work items to be added if there are no work items to be processed.